# Is there a single word for "come out" as in "that stain will never come out"

Tags: single-word-requests

There are words that mean to "take out" - expunge, extricate, remove, extract, etc. But I can't find a word for "come out."
In the sentence "That stain will never come out," the words come out sound very colloquial to me. Is there a single word for this?

Comment: Make no mistake about it, phrasal verbs are not necessarily colloquial. come out is the right verb here. Also: go away. That stain on his reputation will never go away.

Comment: If you want to sound less colloquial you can use “remove”, just recast the sentence, e.g. “That stain could not be removed” or, more naturally, “I couldn’t remove the stain”.  But “come out” is the most appropriate and standard usage.

Comment: …or something involving “the perfumes of Arabia”.

Answer (score 3):

Three words come to mind: *disappear*, *vanish* and *evanish*. Of these I suggest *disappear* and *vanish* as most commonly understood, while *evanish* fits your need well but is not well known. *Vanish* has overtones (below) of sudden disappearance that may not suit  normal stain removal. So perhaps the safest choice is ***disappear***

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disappear)
>
> disappear:
>
> to no longer exist
>
> (of a person or thing) to go to a place or into a condition where the person or thing cannot be seen

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vanish)
>
> vanish
>
> to disappear or stop being present or existing, especially in a sudden, surprising way
>
> to disappear or stop existing, esp. suddenly

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evanish)
>
> evanish: intransitive verb
>
> 1: Vanish, disappear
>
> 2: to cease to be

Answer (score 0):

For a more formal verb, you can use **dissipate,** especially if you want to emphasize the time factor.

**dissipate** (v.)

> *Transitive*
>
> To break up and drive off
>
> *dissipate a crowd*
>
> *Intransitive*
>
> To break up and scatter or vanish
>
> *The clouds dissipated and the sun came out.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissipate)

> When something dissipates or when you dissipate it, it becomes less or
> becomes less strong until it disappears or goes away completely.
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dissipate)

---

> According to experts at The Marble Institute, it often takes four or
> five applications to **dissipate a stain**. [*Old-House Journal*,
> vols. 35, n.5](https://books.google.com/books?id=V-0tWXE01ikC&pg=PA60&dq=%22dissipate%20a%20stain%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0iZ_G2Y71AhUFVt8KHdyXB20Q6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22dissipate%20a%20stain%22&f=false)

> Mount immediately; otherwise, the **stain will dissipate**. [Charles
> Ettensohn et al.; *Development of Sea Urchins...*](http://Development_of_Sea_Urchins_Ascidians_and)

> An oil stain on leather upholstery requires immediate attention.
> "Blot
> up as much of the oil as you can with soft cloths or tissue," Coffey
> says, "then let nature take over. In most cases, the **stain will
> dissipate** as the leather gradually absorbs the remaining oil." [Edward Claflin; *The Experts Book of Practical Secrets*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Experts_Book_of_Practical_Secrets/Usywn58-Y8YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22stain%20will%20dissipate%22&dq=%22stain%20will%20dissipate%22&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Thank you both!